# How do i disable a button after ag-grid loads

Tags: angular, button, dom-events, ag-grid

I have a ag grid with multiple columns and few buttons bellow the ag grid. Here depending on the ag grid value from one of the column i need to disable/enable the buttons.Is it good to go by using event listener or any other methods are available?

Please help me guys !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the ans for the above.
This can be done using below snippets

```
    (firstDataRendered) ="firstDataRendered($event)"
```

Above code in your HTML and the below in component.ts

```
 firstDataRendered(params){
 this.params =params;
 this.gridApi = params.api; // To access the grids API
 this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
 if(this.getProducts().length == 1){
   this.disableRefreshButtons = false;
 }
}
```

Thank you guys for your support.

Answer (score 2):

---

From what you explain, the buttons are related to column value - you can then disable the buttons based on the column cell values (array with values you use calling setRowData function) before ag-grid is initialised.

This can be different if you plan to manipulate the data inside the grid - that will require creating a callback function inside one of the triggers:

- cellValueChanged
- rowValueChanged
- cellEditingStopped

More about it here: [Grid Events](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/)

After your comments - `cellRenderer` should be relevant solution for your needs.

Probably you will use a simple variable as below to indicate current state:

`$scope.previous_page_param = false; //or true regarding user's choice`

And here is the renderer:

```
cellRenderer: function(params) {
    if ($scope.previous_page_param) {
      return '<button type="button">Enabled</button>';
    } else {
      return '<button disabled type="button">Disabled</button>';
    }
}
```

Working code is here: [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-taussig-ecgw8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i need that button to be disabled without any triggers like  cellValueChanged,
rowValueChanged,
cellEditingStopped. On load of the grid it should disable the button. Is there any other way?

Comment: Please give a clear rules when this button should be disabled and based on which value. A sample of the code will be very appreciated. Does it mean also the buttons should be disabled once on grid load or on cell value update?

Comment: Sure, Ag grid will be shown based on the selection criteria from the previous page(i.e our main page user selects product and he comes to ag grid page).Now coming to condition if the user selects single product then button in the ag grid page should be enabled else it should be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my buttons are not inside the ag grid. It's below ag grid. In this case will this work?    <button  [disabled]="disableRefreshButtons" (click)="refreshTotal($event)">Refresh Totals</button>     this code is in my html component and button layout is just below the ag grid.  Does this make sense if i call same in cellRenderer.?

Comment: @Akshay Krishna - your issue has noting to do then with ag-grid. What you need is just verify the params sent by previous page and then set the button state (i do not see any interaction with ag-grid at all). 'cellRenderer' is just a simple function, use the logic as you wish regarding your Angular version.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onGridReady` from `GridOptions` interface then disable your buttons when it gets called.

[Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-reference-overview/)